# Use of page to redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, meta

I need to set up a page to redirect from our old server to our new server, advising people of the new URL and to change their bookmarks.  I know how to use the refresh meta tag in HTML to do this.

But I also want to set it up so that they would see the redirect page no matter what page they have navigated to on the old server.  I see several solutions using 301 redirect.

How would I do both?  We're running an Apache server on Debian server.

Comment: What questions are left after reading the excellent documentation? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Apache an `RewriteRule` using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This can be placed in an `.htaccess` file on your server’s root, or it can be placed directly into your Apache config file.

So let’s say your new redirect page—where you explain the site has moved and have set a refresh meta tag—is called `redirect.php`, then this is the Apache `RewriteRule` that should work for your needs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php [L,R=301]
```

This will grab any URL on the site this `RewriteRule` is placed on & redirect them to `/redirect.php`. That `/redirect.php` can also be a full URL such as `http://mysite.com/redirect.php` or anything else.

Comment: Thanks, Jake; looks good! I'll take this to my "betters" and see when we can implement this solution.  Could be a while, but I'll let you know how it turns out.